# Images and HTML in WPF app

Tags: wpf, user-interface

I have a WPF application where I have a column that should display one of the following:

1. If images are returned, display the images.
2. If a HTML text is returned, render the HTML table within the cell.

Can someone please tell me how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

For **HTML**, you may refer this link - http://pdgp.wordpress.com/2008/05/31/show-html-formatting-in-gridview-cells/

For showing **Image**, you may refer here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ab8kd75.aspx

Hope this helps.

**[Update for Winforms DataGridView]**

In order to display HTML, the only choice would be to override the Paint method I suppose. Alternatively, you may think of hosting a **WebBrowserControl**.

How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells:-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx

Comment: I am doing a winforms app, so HtmlEncode won't work as in web app. Can you please suggest me something that will work for winforms?